# jQuery form validation did not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I used following jQuery script for validate phone numbers. That phone number fields are **not required fields**, but user can not enter incorrect phone numbers. If I enter incorrect phone number then it shows "Please specify a valid phone number" message.

But I can submit form without care that error message, Can someone please advise me how to allow submit form, if only entered phone numbers are correct.

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("fnType", function (phone_number, element) {
        phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "");
        return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
                phone_number.match(/^\+[0-9]{11}$/);
    }, "Please specify a valid phone number");


    jQuery("#EditView").validate({
        rules: {
            phone_work: {
                fnType: true
            },
            phone_fax: {
                fnType: true
            },
            phone_mobile: {
                fnType: true
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please check here it is working fine without any change if you use jquery validator:
https://jsfiddle.net/ganyo55s/

Answer (score 0):

I am using this and it works fine:

```
$.validator.addMethod("nonleadingzero", function(value, element) {
        return /^[1-9][0-9]*$/i.test(value);
    }, 
        "Please enter a valid mobile number"
);

$('#frmId').validate({
    mobile: {
        // other validation, if any
        nonleadingzero: true,
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.validator.addMethod("fnType", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || value.match(/^[\d]*\d[\d]*$/);
    }, "Please enter a valid phone number.");   


jQuery("#EditView").validate({
    rules: {
        phone_work: {
            fnType: true,
            minlength: 10
           }
    }
    messages: {
            phone_work: {
                minlength: "Min length of Phone Number is 10 digits.",
            }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add required false

```
jQuery("#EditView").validate({
    rules: {
        phone_work: {
            fnType: true,
            required: false
        },
        phone_fax: {
            fnType: true,
            required: false
        },
        phone_mobile: {
            fnType: true,
            required: false
        }
    }
});
```